# Passing char to function breaks heap

Tags: c, char, heap-memory, heap-corruption

Psudo code below, but does anyone have any idea why this would be breaking the heap? The urlencode function is a standard library function downloaded elsewhere, and appears to function as designed. In the actual code I'm using dynamic size char arrays, thus the reason for the malloc requirement in main.

```
/* Returns a url-encoded version of str */
/* IMPORTANT: be sure to free() the returned string after use */
char *urlencode(char *str) {
  //char *pstr = str, *buf = malloc(strlen(str) * 3 + 1), *pbuf = buf;
  char *pstr = str, *buf = malloc(strlen(str) * 3 + 1), *pbuf = buf;
  while (*pstr) {
    if (isalnum(*pstr) || *pstr == '-' || *pstr == '_' || *pstr == '.' || *pstr == '~') 
      *pbuf++ = *pstr;
    else if (*pstr == ' ') 
      *pbuf++ = '+';
    else 
      *pbuf++ = '%', *pbuf++ = to_hex(*pstr >> 4), *pbuf++ = to_hex(*pstr & 15);
    pstr++;
  }
  *pbuf = '\0';
  return buf;
}

int testFunction(char *str) {
    char *tmpstr;
    tmpstr = urlencode(str);
    // Now we do a bunch of stuff
    // that doesn't use str
    free(tmpstr);
    return 0;
    // At the end of the function,
    // the debugger shows str equal
    // to "This is a test"
}

int main() {
    char *str = NULL;
    str = malloc(100);
    strcpy(str, "This is a test");
    testFunction(str);
    free(str); // Debugger shows correct value for str, but "free" breaks the heap
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you getting a segfault? Or a double free/heap corruption error specifically?

Comment: No problem here, but if you have `char`s outside the ASCII range, `to_hex(*pstr >> 4)` could cause trouble, it's safer to mask that with `0xF` too.

Comment: Works fine for me, and Valgrind produces no errors.  Are you sure that the code in `// Now we do a bunch of stuff that doesn't use str` doesn't corrupt the heap?  Have you tried running it under Valgrind?

Comment: @Daniel: Yeah, the argument to `isalnum` needs to be in the range 0-255 or `EOF`, so if you pass a non-ASCII signed char, that's undefined behavior.  My GCC gives a warning if the argument to any of those `is*` ctype functions is of a signed character type.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield: Yes, and the way to avoid that is to cast the argument: `isalnum((unsigned char)*pstr)`

Comment: Do you have `#include` directives for `<stdlib.h>` and `<string.h>`? Where and how is `to_hex()` defined? Do you get any compile-time warnings with warning levels cranked up as high as possible (for gcc, `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O3`; optimization enables some warnings)?

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that `str` was already freed by `free(tmpstr);` - please have a look at the behavior of the `urlencode`-function. It seems like it does not generate a new string as return value, but passes the (changed) input string back.

Comment: No, that's not it, it `malloc`s `buf` and returns that.

Answer (score 0):

the problem turned out to be an issue with the size calculation for the initial malloc of str being executed as 0. Thank you for the comments, unfortunately no way to really mark an answer as comments.

If this is an improper way to close this out, please let me know.

Comment: I think you can delete the question. In the future, either post your real code, or verify that the example code actually suffers from the same problem (if it doesn't, the difference may lead you to the solution).